# Using ES6 module with asset pipeline of ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I am converting old functional-based syntax Javascript to ES6 classes .
Previously code was like this :

```
var SW;
if(SW.app === undefined) SW.app = {};
SW.app.NullLicense = (function () {
    "use strict";

    var NullLicense;
    NullLicense = function () { };
    NullLicense.prototype.handleLicense = function () {
        var t1 = new SW.app.Utility();
        return t1;
    };
    return NullLicense;
}());
```

Now with ES6 modules the code is like this

```
import {Utility} from './Utility.js'
export class NullLicense  {
    "use strict";
    constructor(){ };
   handleLicense  () {
        var t1 = new Utility();
        return t1;
    }
};
```

Since previously every module was concatenated to global SW variable we didn't have to worry about the dependencies issue.
In `app/asset` we have our manifest file `application.js` . It loads all the js files in the code base. Now since we have `export`  and `import` commands in every file , I am getting this error that  `export declarations may only appear at top level of a module`.
I want to know what can be the workaround for this .

Thanks

Comment: You're using a highly outdated tool which assembles your assets by just copy-pasting them together. While it may be possible to get it work its most likely a huge waste of time compared to switching to a JS based assets system that actually understands ES6 modules. I would recommend that you just leave the JS it as is for now and focus on updating the Rails application.

Answer (score -2):

Try using Webpacker gem or webpack.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).